# jsoup throws 204 status despite a status code check

Tags: java, jsoup, httpurlconnection

While i connect to a url through jsoup. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
  for (int j = 0; j < unq_urls.size(); j++) {

      Response response2 = Jsoup.connect(unq_urls.get(j))
             .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
             .timeout(100*1000)
             .ignoreContentType(true)
             .execute();

      if (response2.statusCode() == 200) {
...}

}
```

When the connection is executed jsoup throws the following error:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=204, URL=https://www.google.com/gen_204?reason=EmptyURL
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:459)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:475)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:475)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:434)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:181)
    at cseapiandparsing.CSE_Author_Name_Dis.<init>(CSE_Author_Name_Dis.java:187)
    at cseapiandparsing.CSE_Author_Name_Dis.main(CSE_Author_Name_Dis.java:263)
```

How can I overcome this? I mean i want jsoup to pass another URL if it cannot connect to a specific URL. Related to this jsoup also throws time out error when it takes too much time to connect a URL. To this end I have already put .timeout(100*1000) option. However, I was wondering is there a way of passing to another URL if the attempt for the current one takes too long?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a `try-catch` mechanism here.

Surround the `Jsoup.connect` part with a `try` clause, then in your `catch` clause handle the exceptions gracefully, which in your case would be **continuing** to the next loop.

To **skip** the current one if it takes too long, simply set `timeout()` value to your desired waiting period, if it passes that period it will throw a timeout exception, which again will be caught by the `catch` clause.
Try the code I posted below:

```
for (int j = 0; j < unq_urls.size(); j++) {
  try{
      Response response2 = Jsoup.connect(unq_urls.get(j))
         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.21 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1042.0 Safari/535.21")
         .timeout(100*1000)
         .ignoreContentType(true)
         .execute();
  } catch(Exception e) {
      continue; //continue to the next loop if exception occurs
  }
}
```